# Java JPA - Persisting @OneToMany entity

Tags: java, database, jpa, runtime-error

*Hello everyone,*

I'm having these days problem with persisting object which is @OneToMany. Where am having problem is that I'm trying to create both objects (one is OneToMany, other one is ManyToOne), and I want to persist @OneToMany one, and automatically to have @ManyToOne persisted into database also. (**All tables are set autoincrement, and Collection is initialized in constructor of Komponenta.class, I've put just parts which are connected to this problem**). Here's my code:

```
public class Komponenta implements Serializable {

@Id
private Integer idKom;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idKom")
private Collection<Ima> imaCollection = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class Ima implements Serializable {

@Id
private Integer idIma;

@JoinColumn(name = "idKom", referencedColumnName = "idKom")
@ManyToOne
private Komponenta idKom;

}

    // runnable part
    Tools.em.getTransaction().begin();

    Komponenta k = new Komponenta();
    Ima i = new Ima();

    Collection<Ima> list = k.getImaCollection();
    list.add(i);
    k.setImaCollection(list);      

    i.setIdKom(k);

    Tools.em.persist(k);
    Tools.em.getTransaction().commit();
```

I'm getting this type of error from console output:

> Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'idKom' cannot be null
>   Error Code: 1048

Comment: Don't you think id should not be null? You are not setting any value to 'idKom'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT column, you are supposed to use an IDENTITY strategy:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idKom;
```

Which is what you'd get when using AUTO with MySQL:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer idKom;
```

Which is actually equivalent to

```
@Id @GeneratedValue
private Integer idKom;
```

Comment: AUTO actually means it is up to the JPA provider to do what it wants, not necessarily use AUTOINCREMENT on MySQL. The IDENTITY option is the way for reliable behaviour

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything I've needed is to put GeneratedValue annotation with Id of private Integer idKom. That solved my issue.

P.S. Anyone knows why my mySql when inerting into table Komponenta with autoincrement set up, it puts IDs: 1, 51, 101, 151... ?

Comment: Try with @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Answer (score 0):

Either you set value to `idKom` of `Komponenta` instance.

**OR**

Let the id generate automatically

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)//Use strategy accoringly
private Integer idKom;
```